# Set nested div to fill all parents

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am using an internal tool which forces me to nest my HTML div inside several other. It's one of those annoying GUI based web-editors, but I need to use it for work. I'm trying to fade the entire background of the page on load.

Here is my problem :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yAJng

So essentially, I have :

```
<div class="ThisDivIsForcedUponMe">
   ...content...
  <div class="ThisWrapperToo">
     ...content...
     <div id="hover"> //the div I want to work with -- the ONLY place I can put HTML
     </div>
     <div id="content">
       <p>content</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#hover").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    $("#popup").fadeOut();
    });

  $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#hover").fadeOut();
    $("#popup").fadeOut();
    });
```

});

As you can see from the codepen, the divs above my "hover" div are causing me issue - they are not being darkened by my CSS as the width, 100%, only fills up to its immediate parent :

```
#hover{
  position:fixed;
  background:#000;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: .6
}
```

Bearing in mind I cannot change my HTML, how can I make my hover div fill everything on the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify left and top coordinates for `#hover`; this is why they start where "This is another annoying part" paragraph ends instead of from the top of the body. Just add them:

```
#hover{
  position:fixed;
  background:#000;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: .6;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/audcf)

Answer (score 0):

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/diwAh)

I added `top:0;` to your `#hover` CSS. I find it helps to be explicit about positioning (top, left, bottom etc) when using `position` rules.

The result is that the black semi-transparent background to the popup now covers the whole page - I hope this is the correct interpretation of what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `margin-top` on the hover div with a negative value